# Session Timeout Notification in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I am creating an app in IBM Worklight 6.2 for my Organization. I have set session timetout property in worklight.properties to 5 mins.

```
#######################################
    Idle session timeout in minutes
#######################################
serverSessionTimeout=5
```

Its working perfectly fine and user is getting logged out from app, however, its not notifying that session timeout is occurred. Is there any way through which I can notify user that his session is going to expire in a minute or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get notified by Worklight that the session is about to expire.

My suggestion is to create a local timer in the application in order to get an approximation of when the timeout will occur and notify the user accordingly.

This can be achieved for example by implementing `setInterval` in the `onSuccess` callback of `WL.Client.connect` (assuming this is how you are connecting to Worklight Server).

Could be something like this:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: connectSuccess, onFailure: connectFailure});
}

function connectSuccess() {
    setInterval (timesUp, 240000);
    // other things ...
}

function connectFailure() {
    // ...
}

function timesUp() {
    alert ("Session will expire in 1 minute.");
    clearInterval();
    // Maybe show a WL.SimpleDialog instead with buttons 
    // to reset the timeout by performing some action against the server or some such.
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question over this, Is there any way through which I can know that session is already expired?

Comment: You cannot know this before hand. You could implement a client-side timer I guess.